# SQL Server DateDiff() vs MySQL TimestampDiff()

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have migrated my application's database from SQL Server to MySQL.  Now I'm adjusting my application code and I'm running into issues with date functions.  Specifically, it seems like SQL Server's DateDiff() rounds up while MySQL's TimestampDiff() rounds down.  For example:

```
SQL Server: select datediff(day,'2015-11-25 12:00:00', '2015-11-26') returns 1

MySQL: select timestampdiff(day,'2015-11-25 12:00:00', '2015-11-26') returns 0
```

What would be the best way to make MySQL return the same results as SQL Server?  I can't just add 1 to each diff expression in MySQL because in cases where the difference between date1 and date2 are exactly X days apart, the MySQL evaluates exactly as SQL Server evaluates.  For example:

```
SQL Server: select datediff(day,'2015-11-25', '2015-11-26') returns 1

MySQL: select timestampdiff(day,'2015-11-25', '2015-11-26') returns 1
```

EDIT: Comments are only suggesting conversions for differences in DAYs.  I will also need to support differences in SECOND, WEEK, MONTH, YEAR, etc.

Comment: Can you calculate with hours instead ?

Comment: If it helps someone who knows MySQL answer, SQL Server isn't "rounding up"; SQL Server just counts the number of day *boundaries* between the two times. So, for example, the `day` difference between `2015-11-25 23:58:00` and `2015-11-25 23:59:00` is 0, as no boundaries are crossed. However, the `day` difference between `2015-11-25 23:59:00` and  `2015-11-26 00:00:00` is 1, as a day boundary is crossed. If you just stripped the time component off the dates before the comparison, I'm guessing you'd get the same answer with MySQL.

Comment: @matt what about same value with a day appart?

Comment: whats wrong with **[mysql datediff](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)**

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That is an option I've considered.  Basically, change the interval unit (day) to the next smaller unit (hour) and then divide by 24 and round up.  That works for DAY, but I'm not sure how well that will work for other units.  For example, how would I make sure MONTH evaluations calculate the same between the 2 databases?

Comment: If you need only diffences by date change timestamp to date

Comment: @amdixon I don't know MySQL so well, but it certainly looks like that [`datediff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function should do the same job as a SQL Server `day` comparison.

Comment: @amdixon MySQL's datediff only counts the difference in days.  I also need a solution for other intervals, such as SECOND, WEEK, MONTH, YEAR.

Comment: sql server datediff also only counts in days - seems like youre comparing the wrong functions

Comment: @amdixon that is false.  SQL Server DateDiff counts in many units: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this I would write a stored function `SQL_SERVER_DATEDIFF()` as a wrapper around MySQL `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` with adjustments to make it behave like SQL Server `DATEDIFF()` and do a search/replace through the code. This gives you the flexibility to fix this issue as well as any others that might arise in the future.

Comment: That's probably the route I will take.  However, I still need to figure out the best way to translate the various difference units and build that into the function.  Since it now seems that SQL Server counts unit boundaries while MySQL does a rounded down subtraction of the 2 dates, it's starting to prove very tricky.